# How is the feather from the trailer related to what has happened so far in the episodes that have aired?

Tags: game-of-thrones

During the trailer launch of *Game of Thrones* season 8. A feather is shown with a good amount of significance. We have seen this feather related to Robert Baratheon visiting the Crypt of Winterfell but that's the old story.

How is the feather related to season 8 so far what has been aired?